# Scanner input validation in while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I've got to show Scanner inputs in a **while** loop: the user has to insert inputs until he writes "quit". So, I've got to validate each input to check if he writes "quit". How can I do that?

```
while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Insert question code:");
    String question = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insert answer code:");
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    service.storeResults(question, answer); // This stores given inputs on db
}
```

This doesn't work. How can I validate each user input?

Comment: Not sure for how many its the same case, but this actually worked properly for me. Not sure what exactly didn't work for you. Remember to give "quit" only and not any other case versions of it.

Comment: When asking about something that "doesn't work", specify in what way it doesn't work. How did its behavior differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) "Advances this scanner past the current line". So when you call `nextLine()` in the `while` condition, and don't save the return value, you've lost that line of the user's input. The call to `nextLine()` on line 3 returns a different line.

You can try something like this

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Insert question code:");
        String question = scanner.nextLine();
        if(question.equals("quit")){
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Insert answer code:");
        String answer = scanner.nextLine();
        if(answer.equals("quit")){
            break;
        }
        service.storeResults(question, answer);
    }
```

Comment: Why is it that the `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)` is outside the while loop?

Comment: @drewteriyaki: You don't want a new `Scanner` created for every user input. A single Scanner on the single system input stream keeps a consistent state on that stream.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("Insert question code:");
    String question = scanner.nextLine();
    if(question.equals("quit")){
     break;
    }

    System.out.println("Insert answer code:");
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    service.storeResults(question, answer); // This stores given inputs on db
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` and `while (true)` (like in Ruchira's answer) in this case?

Comment: while(true) will terminate only in break and while(scanner.hasNextLine()) terminate at EOF.

Comment: But how can it reach the end of file if there will always be a `scanner.nextLine()` (even if empty)?

Answer (score 0):

always check if scanner.nextLine is not "quit"

```
while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Insert question code:");
    String question = scanner.nextLine();
    if(question.equals("quit"))
     break;

    System.out.println("Insert answer code:");
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();
    if(answer.equals("quit"))
      break;

    service.storeResults(question, answer); // This stores given inputs on db
```

}