# How do you get a Scanner to store and repeat in a while loop

Tags: java

I need to write a program which accepts non-negative double type of
 numbers as
income amounts one by one unti
l a negative number
 is entered
, and the negative number ends the 
program. When the program is completed by entering a negative number
, it prints out the 
minimum, average, and maximum for the set of entered incomes (excluding the last negative 
number
 be
cause it only indicates the end of user input).

```
package incomeapp;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Kenneth
 */
public class IncomeApp {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an income (any negative number to quit: ");
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double i = sc.nextDouble();
        while (i > 0){
            double nextDouble;     
            nextDouble = sc.nextDouble();
             if (i < 0){
                 break;
             }    
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Also if you want to stop on a negative it should be while i>=0 the breal is unnecessary

Comment: In your while loop, the condition should be i>=0 and remove the if break. Also it should be i = sc.nextDouble() forget about your neXtDouble double, so whem user enters negative it will break out of the loop. Just store i in some array then loop through it at the end to get and calculate your output values

Comment: It doesnt repeat after i input a number

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950713/scanner-input-validation-in-while-loop?rq=1 for an example

Comment: Why the `java-8` tag?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with your code here:

1. You never actually increment either *sum* or *count*
2. You read input into *i* before the loop, but then you read into *nextDouble* inside the loop and the loop condition only checks *i* - which never changes.
3. You never print out the minimum, average, and maximum
4. The condition in the while and if statements are redundant (apart from the if condition accepting *0* which the while condition doesn't)

Now, this seems very much like a programming assignment to me so I'm not going to post the complete code for you. Here's what you should do to fix your code though:

1. Increment *sum* and *count* in the loop.
2. Use **either** *i* or *nextDouble* - not both.
3. Print the desired output after the loop
4. Pick one way of terminating the loop. Here's two ideas on how to do it:

   ```
   double i = sc.nextDouble();
   while (i > 0) {
       // Do something with i
       i = sc.nextDouble();
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   while (true) {
       double i = sc.nextDouble();
       if (i <= 0) {
           break;
       }
       // Do something with i
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter an income (any negative number to quit: ");
            double sum = 0;
            double max = 0;
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int count = 0;
            double nextDouble;
            while (sc.hasNext()) {    
                nextDouble = sc.nextDouble();
                max = Math.max(max, nextDouble);
                 if (nextDouble < 0){                        
                     break;
                 }else {
                    min = Math.min(nextDouble, min);
                    sum += nextDouble;
                    count++;
                 }
            }
       System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
       System.out.println("Min: " + min);
       System.out.println("Max: " + max);
     }
}
```