# Provide loop conditions that are not Boolean

Tags: java, loops, boolean, conditional-statements, java.util.scanner

I need to accept some positive integers for which I use a for loop as follows:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
    num = in.nextInt(); 
    //do something with num
}
```

This requires me to (a) know number of integers *n* beforehand (b) Use a counter *i*

I know Java does not accept non-Boolean expressions in loop conditions. But how can I do the same without *n* and *i*?
For example, something like:

```
while( (num = in.nextInt()) ) {
   //do something with num
}
```

Any type of loop (for/while/do-while) will do.

Comment: What do you want the stopping condition to be (i.e. when should the loop be terminated)?

Comment: All loop conditions are boolean. Either you stop or you don't stop looping.

Comment: You can use in.nextLine() to read a line as string, check if that string is 'exit' or something like that and then step out your loop otherwise parse that string to interger and continue processing your number.

Comment: Hope this will helps you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950713/scanner-input-validation-in-while-loop

Comment: @NoEm - If you're only interested in ints, using in.hasNextInt() as the condition automatically terminates on *ANY* non-integer input. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop until end of input *-or-* non-integer input (e.g. "exit", blank line):

```
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
    int num = in.nextInt();
}
```

If you're testing in IntelliJ and want to indicate EOF explicitly: `Ctrl+D or ⌘+D`
If you want to read a file as your input: `java MyClass < numbers.txt`

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is something like:

```
boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {
  int num = in.nextInt();
  ... do something with n
  if (whatever) loop = false;
}
```

for example.

Or you use `while (true)` together with `if (whatever) break`.

In other words: you need a boolean condition, but you can *control* that condition within your loop body as shown above.

Comment: This method works, but I want to minimize LOC and variable use. Your solution requires tracking the boolean 'loop' and also a comparison (i.e. 'if'). In larger codes with multiple loops, I would either have to use the same control variable 'loop' (which saves space but becomes hard to track), or use multiple variables.

Comment: In larger codes ... you follow clean code principles such as "single layer of abstraction". You simply **never** write a method that contains more than one loop. It is that simple. In other words: when you are really interested in writing nice, human readable **clean** code ... then you worry about much more than just simple loop conditions.

Comment: I see your point. I shall look into the 'single layer of abstraction' principle. Actually I'm used to C/C++ and wanted to know how to get around Java's 'int is not boolean' feature (see my comment on TwoThe's answer) .Thank you!

Comment: @agentK You are welcome. But please understand that this is more than just one principle. When you are serious about this, get yourself a copy of "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. And be willing to spend many hours thinking about this topic. This takes many months of practice to get fully into.

Comment: @agentK And I noticed that you could only accept so far. Enabled you to also upvote - so you can show your appreciation on all postings that you deem helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use the scanner class: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

You should use the `hasNext()` method to end the loop and check for integers with the `hasNextInt()` method:

```
public class ScannerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";

       // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

       // find the next int token and print it
       // loop for the whole scanner
       while (scanner.hasNext()) {

           // if the next is a int, print found and the int
           if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
               System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextInt());
           }

           // if no int is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
           System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
       }

       // close the scanner
       scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know Java does not accept non-Boolean expressions in loop conditions.

To my knowledge no programing language allows that. The loop either continues or it does not, this is a boolean decision and that requires a boolean conditional. There is no "the loop maybe continues, we don't know".

With that said Java - of course - requires a boolean condition to continue or not. The question you need to answer is: When shall the loop terminate?

There are three options:

**The loop continues forever**

```
while (true)
```

**The loop stops at a special input value**

```
while ((num = in.readInt()) != 0)
```

**The loop is broken from outside**

```
while (running) {
  // ...
}

public void stopLoop() { 
  running= false; 
}
```

Comment: In C `while ( (num = ...) )` would throw no compile error and will be kind of interpreted as boolean. I think this is what the OP meant by non-boolean...

Comment: This is because in C `0` is considered `false` This is exactly the same as option 2.

Comment: Yes, but `num` is of type `int` in this case and for java "not a boolean"

Comment: @TwoThe I'm afraid I didn't get my point across very well. I want to simplify my code. As m13r said, C allows while ( num=in.nextInt() ) but Java doesn't because 'int' is not a 'boolean' in Java. hasNextInt() solves the problem.

Comment: At which point does `hasNextInt()` of a Scanner on `System.in` return false?

Comment: @TwoThe - See my answer. Either when the Scanner reads EOF (e.g. if stdin is coming from a file and we've read to the end) or when the next token is not an integer.

Comment: Note: You're missing a very common use case: when the loop is broken from the *inside*, either through calling `break` or by changing the loop condition e.g. `running=false`. A local boolean is much cleaner than a field.